# What is the difference between "screen" and "only screen" in media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference between `screen` and `only screen` in media queries?

```
<link media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="m.css" />
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="m.css" />
```

Why are we required to use `only screen`? Does `screen` not itself provide enough information to be rendered **only** for screen?

I've seen many responsive websites using any of these three different ways:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:632px)
```

```css
@media (max-width:632px)
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:632px)
```

Answer (score 674):

Let's break down your examples one by one.

```
@media (max-width:632px)
```

This one is saying for a window with a `max-width` of 632px that you want to apply these styles. At that size you would be talking about anything smaller than a desktop screen in most cases.

```
@media screen and (max-width:632px)
```

This one is saying for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of 632px apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the [other available media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)  the most common other one being `print`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:632px)
```

Here is a quote straight from W3C to explain this one.

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User   agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "only", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

Here's the [link to that quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) that is shown in example 9 on that page.

Hopefully this sheds some light on media queries.

EDIT:

Be sure to check out [@hybrids excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168210/1078110) on how the `only` keyword is really handled.

Comment: For anyone who was looking for a better explanation of *why* the `only` keyword will hide style sheets from older browsers, see the answer by @hybrid below.  He explains it very well.

Comment: hybrid's answer is good, but I like this answer too because it addresses media queries *inside CSS* as opposed to only addressing the `media` attribute of the `link` element.

Comment: what device doesnt have a screen?

Comment: @Kokodoko ones that don't need one. But seriously, printers and screen readers don't necessarily have screens. Plus anything else currently or in the future that don't identify as `screen` such as anything listed in the other media types.

Comment: thx :) it just seems a bit redundant in a world where all we really do is design for screens. CSS exists because we have screens :)

Comment: @Kokodoko CSS exists to create a separation of concerns between content and presentation. Presentation covers much more than just what can be seen on a screen. It's an important distinction to keep in mind regardless of what you might be designing for.

Comment: I stopped reading this answer when he said "This one is saying for a device with a screen". Is there a device without a screen?

Comment: @MaXi32 yes. If you look at the other media types it's pretty obvious that there are things without screens. Things like `print`, `braille`, and `speech` aren't about screens. To copy an older comment of mine: CSS exists to create a separation of concerns between content and presentation. Presentation covers much more than just what can be seen on a screen.

Answer (score 289):

The following is from [**Adobe docs**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html).

---

The media queries specification also provides the keyword `only`, which is intended to hide media queries from older browsers. Like `not`, the keyword must come at the beginning of the declaration. For example:

```
media="only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)"
```

Browsers that don't recognize media queries expect a comma-separated list of media types, and the specification says they **should** truncate each value immediately before the first nonalphanumeric character that isn't a hyphen. So, an old browser **should** interpret the preceding example as this:

```
media="only"
```

Because there is no such media type as only, the stylesheet is ignored. Similarly, an old browser **should** interpret

```
media="screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px)"
```

as

```
media="screen"
```

In other words, it should apply the style rules to all screen devices, even though it doesn't know what the media queries mean.

**Unfortunately, IE 6–8 failed to implement the specification correctly.**

Instead of applying the styles to all screen devices, it ignores the style sheet altogether.

In spite of this behavior, it's still recommended to prefix media queries with only if you want to hide the styles from other, less common browsers.

---

So, using

```
media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)"
```

and

```
media="screen and (min-width: 401px)"
```

will have the same effect in IE6-8: both will prevent those styles from being used. They will, however, still be downloaded.

Also, in browsers that support CSS3 media queries, both versions will load the styles if the viewport width is larger than `401px` and the media type is screen.

I'm not entirely sure which browsers that don't support CSS3 media queries would need the `only` version

```
media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)"
```

as opposed to

```
media="screen and (min-width: 401px)"
```

to make sure it is not interpreted as

```
media="screen"
```

It would be a good test for someone with access to a device lab.

Comment: So if we are talking about media queries in CSS files, we can drop "only", because older browsers don't understand media queries whatsoever, Can't we?

Comment: According to my experience, "only" is working as expected on Symbian OS (old Nokia touch phones). I used it a lot because those browser was really bad in CSS3 support, but it was still able to handle "only" and "min/max-width" in media queries right.

Comment: @PeterKnut Why are you even supporting such old devices? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @Hasim, I wrote my comment in past tense: "I used it a lot" :) In current days, it is not necessery to support such archaic devices. I just wanted to say that `only screen` was usefull and in fact the only way how to avoid broken page because of tragic CSS3 support.

Answer (score 48):

To style for many smartphones with smaller screens, you could write:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) { … }
```

To block older browsers from seeing an iPhone or Android phone style sheet, you could write:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px;) { … }
```

Read this article for more http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/a/css3-media-queries.htm

Comment: I'm still not very clear on it. I've updated my question too. Can you give any example?

Comment: What if you use the Mobile First approach? So, we have the mobile css first and then use min-width to target larger sites. We shouldn't use the `only` keyword in that context, right?

Comment: This answer was alot easy to understand! :) The only is just to keep the older versions such as IE 6 or opera 5 or 6 from loading the data that has to be presented for Android or Chrome 30 or IE 10..Exellent answer sandeep :) deserves a +1

Answer (score 24):

The answer by @hybrid is quite informative, except it doesn't explain the purpose as mentioned by @ashitaka  "What if you use the Mobile First approach? So, we have the mobile CSS first and then use min-width to target larger sites. We shouldn't use the only keyword in that context, right? "

Want to add in here that the purpose is simply to prevent non supporting browsers to use that Other device style as if it starts from "screen" without it will take it for a screen whereas if it starts from "only" style will be ignored.

Answering to ashitaka consider this example

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="android.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" />
```

If we don't use "only" it will still work as desktop-style will also be used striking android styles but with unnecessary overhead. In this case, IF a browser is non-supporting it will fallback to the second Style-sheet ignoring the first.

Answer (score 3):

```css
@media screen and (max-width:480px) { … }
```

`screen` here is to set the screen size of the media query. E.g the maximum width of the display area is 480px. So it is specifying the screen as opposed to the other available media types.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px;) { … }
```

`only screen`  here is used to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles.

Comment: only is used to support older browsers that do not support media queries. So if we use only, the older browsers will support this query? Kinda confuse here.

Answer (score 1):

### What is the difference between "screen" and "only screen" in media queries?

Media queries is used to create responsive web design. Both the `screen` and `only screen` are used in media queries.

**`screen`**: It is used to set the screen size of media query. The screen size can be set by using max-width and min-width.

`screen` is used to style for many smartphones with smaller screens, you could write:

```
@media screen and (max-width:630px){ ... }
```

In the above code `screen` is saying for a screen and window size with a max-width of 630px, you want to apply said styles.

**`only screen`**: The only keyword is used to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles.

To block older browsers from seeing the stylesheet, you will write:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:630px){ ... }
```

*The keyword ‘only’ will hide style sheets from older user agents.*