# CSS media queries - min-device-width and max-device-width

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

I have problem adding CSS for a specific device.

I ran my app on these two simulator:

1. width: 320 and height: 500
2. width: 320 and height: 588

Now, my problem is, the CSS always used is the second one : 320 x 588. I believe that it is because it qualifies with the `min-device-width` which is `320`. So how could I use the first CSS `320x500` with the device having width: 320 and height: 500?

I am not really familiar with `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`.

/* IOS ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 500px) {
   //style here
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 588px) {
   //style here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite it into

```
 @media only screen  and (max-device-width : 320px)
```

that means that the media query triggers on a resolution below 320px

and your other breakpoint should be like:

```
@media only screen  and (max-device-width : 588px)
```

if I got your intention right. But after searching here for a short time, needless to say the question was asked before, so before I start copy-pasting answers, just have a quick look at this topic

[What is the difference between "screen" and "only screen" in media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries)

i hope it helps you to get it better.
with br paulq