# Applying media queries more efficiently

Tags: javascript, css, html

I wrote a sample code to try media queries in css...
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 374px) and (max-device-width: 376px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #img {
        background-color: blue; 
    }
button {
        margin: auto;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Media queries are simple filters that can be applied to CSS styles. They make it easy to change styles based on the characteristics of the device rendering the content, including the display type, width, height, orientation and even resolution.</p>
<button>Click me!</button>
<image src='Promo_2-2.jpg' id='img' alt='image'></image>
</body>
</html>
```

but media queries aren't working. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing the queries on a computer, then there is nothing wrong with your queries.  Remember this:  `min-device-width` calculates the width of your device, while `min-width` calculates the window size.  Your Media Query should look like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 374px) and (max-width: 376px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #img {
        background-color: blue; 
    }
button {
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

And about the `only` keyword, here's what the Mozilla Developer Network says:

***The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the given styles:***

***`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (color)" href="example.css" />`***

### [Learn more about Media Queries here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Well... what is the difference between `@media only screen` and `@media screen`?

Comment: That question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because the keyword 'only.
The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents'.
User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

You can check this information at w3.org: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0 - example 9