# Z-Index does not work on my Magento Theme

Tags: css, themes, magento-1.9

i have a problem with z-index on my webpage, i need move shopping bottons to the top -100px but when i try it the button loose the actions not work anymore, i try to use z-index: 99999 but not work too, i need some help! here my page link limitx.panamerik.net

----IMAGES-----

This is the real image:

[image]

**I need make this:**

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CSS.

Comment: @user17142 I just updated my answer (again), now added `<CSS>` for the slider arrows as well. This should work now, even though is doesn't look very elegant...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** After looking at your screen shots again I realized that you want to display the button to the right of the product images. I'm not sure if this is a good idea, because this theme is meant to be responsive.

But if you really, really, really want to do this then you may try to add the following `<CSS>` to your `custom.css` file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .products-grid .actions {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        right: -25px;
    }
    .owl-wrapper {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .slider-arrows1 .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev, .slider-arrows1 .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

This will work as you can see in the screen shot below, when hovering the button.

[image]

I have added `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)` because of the responsive nature of the theme. Otherwise, when the browser viewport gets smaller, the buttons would overlap the image. You may want to play a little with this setting and should test it on some mobile devices too.

To learn more about this see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries).

---

> **EDIT:** I'll leave my original answer below, just in case this may
>   helpful to someone else in the future...

I see that you use Infortis Ultimo theme, which is a great choice. I don't think you should use `<CSS>` to move the button. It is better to move the entire `<div class="actions"></div>` to the top.

The result will look like this:

[image]

You can do this by making some changes to the following file:

```
app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Somewhere around lines 273 to 289 (depending on the themes version) you will find the code for this:

```
<div class="actions clearer<?php echo $actionsClasses; ?>">

    ....

</div> <!-- end: actions -->
```

> **Note:** It is best to first copy the entire `list.phtml` file to your own sub-theme
>   and make the changes there.

In your sub-themes `list.phtml` file just cut the section I mentioned above and move it up to somewhere around line 216 of the file.

Paste it right after the beginning of the `<list class="item">` element and before the `<div class="product-image-wrapper"....>`, just like this:

```
<li class="item">

    <!-- PUT THE CODE HERE -->

    <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:<?php echo $imgWidth; ?>px;">
```

Also don't forget to add this in your `custom.css` style sheet:

```
.products-grid .actions {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

This should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using top value in negative that means there could be problems with the followings:

1. the parent div is set to `overflow:hidden;` and don't show the element i.e. hide the element going behind the parent div. (remove `overflow:hidden` from the parent)
2. z-index value is not working? You didn't explicitly declared the position. (set `position:relative` or absolute)