# Inner Div font Size won't change with media queries when resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I need help resizing the font-size inside of a div. So that when I resize the browser window it changes to a smaller font.**

I can't change the html font or body font so the solution must target the h1 inside the specific div. I'm opened to a media query solution or even js.
I've tried all other similar questions and answers with no solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/x767knu0/

HTML:

```
<div class="sharesmenu">
             <h1>Jake's Shares</h1>  
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen only (max-width:1405px) {
    .sharesmenu h1 { font-size:1em; }
}

@media screen only (min-width: 1406px) {
     .sharesmenu h1  { font-size:2.2em; }
}
```

Comment: `@media screen and ... `OR `@media only screen and ...`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries - basically the CSS you have is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your media queries incorrectly.

You have called `only screen` the wrong way round and you are also missing the `and` join which tells the browser to check for more than one variable.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sharesmenu h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .sharesmenu h1 {
    font-size: 2.2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sharesmenu">
  <h1>Pepe Corse</h1> 
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x767knu0/2/)

Comment: Great, that solved my problem. Also it turns out I had another copy of the code in my css preventing the font from resizing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of your CSS in that fiddle and then resize the browser.:

```
@media (max-width:1405px) {
    h1 { 
        font-size:1em; 
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1406px) {
    h1 { 
        font-size:2.2em; 
    }
}
```