# CSS/SCSS media query or class

Tags: css, sass

i need run the same style with media query and class.
  For example i need set 200px when screen is less then 500px or when have class .active.
  How do this in smart way? Without copy/paste code?

Not working:

```
@media(max-width: 500px), .active {
      width: 200px;
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

In css, the **`,`** is used for grouping, when the same rule applies for several selectors.

However, [media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) are not selectors. They consist of a media type and zero or more expressions to check the condition of [particular media features](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1). Thus, the **`,`** will not work in this case.

If you want to keep it dry, you can give their mixin feature a try.

**E.g**

```
@mixin smallWidth() {
    width: 200px;
}

.elem {
    &.active {
        @include smallWidth;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
        @include smallWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's **and**, the question says **or**

Answer (score 15):

Mixins are a simple solution, but they duplicate the CSS in the final output. A better solution may be to inverse the logic entirely.

In boolean algebra, **de Morgan's theorem** states that `A || B` is the same as `!(A && B)`. In your case, this means thinking about your problem in a mobile-first way:

```
.elem {
  width: 200px;

  @media (min-width: 501px) {
    &:not(.active) {
      width: auto; // or whatever
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to think. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

CSS provides no means to say "When a media query OR a given class applies".

With plain CSS you can only:

```
.active {
    width: 200px;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
      * {
          width: 200px;
      }
}
```

with SASS you can use a mixin, but it isn't really efficient for a single rule like that:

```
@mixin my-width {
    width: 200px;
}

.active {
    @include my-width;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
      * {
          @include my-width;
      }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this one.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .active {
          width: 200px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you explain what "only screen" accomplishes? :)

Comment: That's **and**, the question says **or**

Comment: @Nelson Tan, thanks, but this is not works for my. I need OR query.
Now add width only when have .active class.

Comment: @jogoe Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries

Answer (score -4):

you have to declare the media and your class separated:

```
@media(max-width: 500px) { .active {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's **and**, the question says **or**