# Media queries work when zoomed on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have some media queries like this-

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .zigzag-lines{
        display: none;
    }

    .decor-single-quote {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .zigzag-lines{
        display: block;
    }

    .decor-single-quote {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

These work when the page is zoomed on a desktop but when I load it on mobile, it doesn't.
I've also included this meta tag in HTML-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I'm using flex from bootstrap-4 so I can't use d-sm-none. (It affects the design)

Can someone explain why it isn't working? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most phone screen sizes are below 576px (which is the min width that you have listed right now. A common breakpoint for a mobile layout would be:

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

There a various sites that go into pixel density on phones and breakpoints for each specific mobile phone.

https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Also, what is 'only screen'? seems to work without it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries

Comment: ^ that explains it well

Answer (score 1):

If that's all the CSS you have, there are no media queries for screens below 576px width, so if you open it on a mobile phone less than 576px wide, the default styles apply (which is `display: block`)