# SASS - Unknown Error Keeps Showing when converting into css

Tags: sass

I'm trying to convert scss file to css, but the error( expected "{" ) shows in following line.

```css
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
2 only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
3 only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi),
4 only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
5     -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
6 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove comma's in the first 3 lines. Also, I would keep 'only screen' only in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (LibSass compiler)

```
@media 
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

... But I would keep it simple (96dpi = 1dppx). Also drop the "[only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries/14168210#14168210) hack" IMO it's not needed

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), // Webkit
       screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {              // Everyone else
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```