# What does the 'only screen' code mean in a css media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

What does the 'only screen' code mean in a media query?

```
//See below the 'only screen' part of the code
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px)
```

I have used code that works without the 'only screen' part of the code. What does it do or how does it help?

Comment: That is the duplicate question, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595600/7412827

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

> only: The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support
>   media queries with media features from applying the specified styles.
>   It has no effect on modern browsers.

The `screen` keyword references that it's a computer, mobile phone or tablet etc. There are two other media types, `print` and `speech`, as well as the default `all`.

Simply: The `only` keyword is optional and used for backwards compatibility. The `screen` keyword will default to `all`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px)
```

As you said and it's true that code can run without **`only screen`** but when you use it that means you are only targeting screens like desktop, laptop, tablet, mobile etc. screen devices not other media devices like printing media and screen readers etc.

resource: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html