# Media Query for all platforms, which one is the correct syntax

Tags: html, css, media-queries

With respect to the following link:

[What is the difference between "screen" and "only screen" in media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries)

"only" is used in media-query so that old browsers, which do not support `media query` should read only (and as hyphenated or alphabets are not present, but a space - they will stop further reading) and the rest of the code will not be applied (as 'only' is not a device type).

In conclusion, we should always write "only" as good practice and our code will be like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 800px) { ... }
```

But, with that logic and applying `only` to prevent old browsers from messing up code whhile they don't support media query and otherwise `screen` keyword after being read - the following CSS will be applied globally (see the link above).

Now, what if I want to write certain media query for `all platforms`, viz. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

What should my correct code be now:

```
@media only all and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) { ... }
```

OR

```
@media all and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) { ... }
```

Remember, `all` is a device-type keyword, so with the same logic, older-browsers will (if only keyword is not used), whatever CSS code is present will be applied globally.

On the other hand I have never seen a code such as `only all` so what I expect is to be syntactically-wrong and CSS will not run.

Now, can someone provide me solution with reason, which of the 2 options is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since all browsers right now support media query you can just use `@media` and it will work without any problem. Also bootstrap uses `@meida` which is something that works on all browsers right now.

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) { ... }
```

Therefore you just need to use `@media` and you will get the same result as if you used

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) { ... }
```

Please refer to this link am sure it will be helpful [MDN @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Also, this link is extremely useful [MDN media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)