# why media queries is not working with django css styling?

Tags: html, css, django, media-queries

Below is the HTML tag

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="{% static 'img/sunil.png' %}" id="logo"  alt="">
</div>
```

**STYLE.CSS**

what i have done in css file is below:

```
#logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 120px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .logo {
        height: 20px;
        width: 60px;
    }
}
```

I tried to change the image size using media queries but it is not working.

style.css is connected in main file because when I use #logo and changed height and width then its working but when I try in media queries then it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your media query is not working. Firstly, make sure you have in your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also, try removing `only` from your media query:

```
#logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 120px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #logo {
        height: 20px;
        width: 60px;
    }
}
```

Note you use `logo` id only once in a page. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries) you can see the difference between screen and only screen.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have meta tag in html's Head section and check if you're targetting div with class .logo or img  with id #logo
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code "logo" is an id.

```
  <img src="{% static 'img/sunil.png' %}" id="logo"  alt="">
```

but here,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .logo {
        height: 20px;
        width: 60px;
    }
}
```

you defined as a class.
try changing the .logo with #logo