# Why does @media min-width not override my CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

In the CSS code my class is ok but for some reason when I go to the Chrome dev tools I can see that media gets "triggered" on 600px but it doesn't override my CSS. Anyone know why?

```css
.main__text{
    color:red;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 1rem 0 2rem 0;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    p{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s probably a specificity problem - the selector for `.main__text` is much more specific than simply `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `!important` flag to your CSS.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    p{
        font-size: 1rem !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain your code and why it is suitable for the given question?

Answer (score 0):

Class selectors take priority over tag selectors (re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Add a class to the `p` you'd like to change and target that.

```css
.main__text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0 2rem 0;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .main__text__alt {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="main__text">Some Text</p>
<p class="main__text main__text__alt">Some Text that will change color and size at 600px</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your html but change the 'p' selector to '.main__text'.

try this:

```css
.main__text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0 2rem 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .main__text {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

An easier way to understand media queries would be trying this:

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Also keep in mind that 'min-width' and 'max-width' act oppositely... 'min-width' applies those styles when the screen size becomes larger than the specified unit while 'max-width' applies the style when the screen size smaller than the specified unit.

Answer (score -1):

For the `@media` to work you need to specify something like `screen` like this:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 p {
  font-size: 1rem;
 }
}
```

Comment: No. Specifying the default media, `screen`, or even `only screen` has been common for backward compatibility, but modern browsers don't need it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries