# CSS styles don't appear

Tags: css

My CSS styles which responsive for small screens don;t appear when i inspect the web page and make it a small screen. It just appear for milli seconds and then vanished.

```
@media(max-width:700px){
    .text-box h1{
        font-size:20px;
    }
```

i'm just watching a youtube video and trying to make this web side. In the video it does appear in small screens when he inspect the web page as a side menu.

Answer (score -1):

From the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595600/17235431) that answers the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8549529/17235431) about the difference between `only screen` and `screen`, these are the points:

```css
@media(max-width:700px) { ... }
```

Styles are applied for a **window** with a max width of `700px`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { ... }
```

Styles are applied for a **window** *and* a **screen** with a max width of `700px`.

As the inspector can vary the screen size, the difference can't been seen, whereas if you resize your window, the changes are visible.